# MongoDB limit memory

Tags: performance, ubuntu, mongodb, debian

I am using mongo for storing log files. Both mongoDB and mysql are running on the same machine, virtualizing mongo env is not an option. I am afraid I will soon run into perf issues as the logs table grows very fast. Is there a way to limit resident memory for mongo so that it won't eat all available memory and excessively slow down the mysql server?

DB machine: Debian 'lenny' 5

Other solutions (please comment):

- As we need all historical data, we can not use capped collections, but I am also considering using a cron script that dumps and deletes old data
- Should I also consider using smaller keys, as suggested on other forums?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hey Vlad, you have a couple of simple strategies here regarding logs.

The first thing to know is that Mongo can generally handle lots of successive inserts without a lot of RAM. The reason for this is simple, you only insert or update recent stuff. So the index size grows, but the data will be constantly paged out.

Put another way, you can break out the RAM usage into two major parts: index & data.

If you're running typical logging, the data portion is constantly being flushed away, so only the index really stays in RAM.

The second thing to know is that you can mitigate the index issue by putting logs into smaller buckets. Think of it this way. If you collect all of the logs into a date-stamped collection (call it `logs20101206`), then you can also control the size of the index in RAM.

As you roll over days, the old index will flush from RAM and it won't be accessed again, so it will simply go away.

> but I am also considering using a cron script that dumps and deletes old data

This method of logging by days also helps delete old data. In three months when you're done with the data you simply do `db.logs20101206.drop()` and the collection instantly goes away. Note that you don't reclaim disk space (it's all pre-allocated), but new data will fill up the empty spot.

> Should I also consider using smaller keys, as suggested on other forums?

Yes.

In fact, I have it built into my data objects. So I access data using `logs.action` or `logs->action`, but underneath, the data is actually saved to `logs.a`. It's really easy to spend more space on "fields" than on "values", so it's worth shrinking the "fields" and trying to abstract it away elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer :)

Comment: However, isn't there any way to specify to OS that the resident memory for mongo should not be bigger than XXX MB?

Comment: Probably, but it won't be a generic answer. It will probably even vary between Linux versions and your mileage will definitely vary. The easiest solution is really just to build the system so that it remains performant in low memory conditions. We're running a similar logging system in production and it's doing several million writes / day on about 1 GB of RAM. (Shared RAM and CPU with other processes, but it has its own disk)

Answer (score 1):

For version 3.2+, which uses wiredTiger engine, the option `--wiredTigerCacheSizeGB` is relevant to the question. You can set it if you know what you are exactly doing. I don't know if it's best practice, just read from the [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--wiredTigerCacheSizeGB) and raise it here.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows it seems possible to control the amount of memory MongoDB uses, see this tutorial at Captain Codeman:

[Limit MongoDB memory use on Windows without Virtualization](http://www.captaincodeman.com/2011/02/27/limit-mongodb-memory-use-windows/)

Comment: This works, but has a limit of 2GB.  e.g. you can't specify that you want to limit the mongo memory to 4GB.

Comment: @Ron   Not true.   The 32-bit version of MongoDB has a process size limitation of 2GB (as does any other process in the 32-bit version of Windows).    You can specify a limit of 4GB, but you'll need a 64-bit machine, 64-bit Windows, and the 64-bit version of Mongo.

Comment: @Curt, I was all 64-bit and had problem with Mongo using more memory than 2GB, so not a 32-bit issue.  From the link I gave above, Captain Codeman says in his blog that there is a limitation of the Windows virtualization with only being able to limit 2GB and gave link to Microsoft connect (which stated the problem), though the link is now invalid.  From my experience this is what I saw also.  e.g.  set limit to 2GB it worked,  set limit to 2.1GB and the memory grew to  12GB.

Comment: @Ron   I'm using it now on Windows Server 2012, with a memory limit of 4MB, and it's respecting the limit quite precisely.    Unfortunately, Microsoft has deprecated the Resource Manager (although it's still present in Windows 2012), as they would prefer that you virtualize it (and buy more licenses).   But it solves my problem for the next year or two, anyway...

Comment: @Curt, thanks for the info.  I believe I was using Windows 2008 R2, so sounds like they fixed the issue on 2012.  That is good to know. We were able to fix our memory problem on Mongo by using usePowerOf2Sizes (now default in Mongo 2.6), it was a fragmentation issue. thx!