# how to release the caching which is used by Mongodb?

Tags: caching, mongodb

Mongodb use the Memory Mapped File ,when I use a long time , I see the free memory has left less by command 'free -m' in ubuntu and the caching use a lot. Then kill the Mongodb the caching still cost a lot ? how can I release the caching ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

MongoDB will (at least seem) to use up a lot of available memory, but it actually leaves it up to the OS's VMM to tell it to release the memory (see [Caching](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Caching) in the MongoDB docs.)

***You should be able to release any and all memory by restarting MongoDB.***

However, to some extent MongoDB isn't really "using" the memory.

For example from the MongoDB docs [Checking Server Memory Usage](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Checking+Server+Memory+Usage) ...

> Depending on the platform you may see
>   the mapped files as memory in the
>   process, but this is not strictly
>   correct. Unix top may show way more
>   memory for mongod than is really
>   appropriate. The Operating System (the
>   virtual memory manager specifically,
>   depending on OS) manages the memory
>   where the "Memory Mapped Files"
>   reside. This number is usually shown
>   in a program like "free -lmt".
>
> It is called "cached" memory.

MongoDB uses the LRU ([Least Recently Used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Least_Recently_Used)) cache algorithm to determine which "pages" to release, you will find some more information in these two questions ...

- [MongoDB limit memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365224/mongodb-limit-memory)
- [MongoDB index/RAM relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811299/mongodb-index-ram-relationship)
- [Mongod start with memory limit](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/2646a52c4f41d832/c5579706d733c21a?lnk=gst&q=memory&pli=1) (You ***can't***.)

Comment: Thx! MongoDB can use all free memory on the server for cache space automatically without any configuration of a cache size. How can we configuration ?

Comment: There is no way to limit cache size ... by design. Here is some more detail on that: http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/2646a52c4f41d832/c5579706d733c21a?lnk=gst&q=memory&pli=1

Comment: You might want to look at this post however and see if it will help you ... http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/12/10/reclaiming-memory-from-mongodb-indexes/

Comment: Why can't you use `ulimit` for this?

Answer (score 14):

Starting in 3.2, MongoDB uses the WiredTiger as the default storage engine. Previous versions used the MMAPv1 as the default storage engine.

With WiredTiger, MongoDB utilizes both the WiredTiger internal cache and the filesystem cache.
In MongoDB 3.2, the WiredTiger internal cache, by default, will use the larger of either: 60% of RAM minus 1 GB, or 1 GB.
For systems with up to 10 GB of RAM, the new default setting is less than or equal to the 3.0 default setting (For MongoDB 3.0, the WiredTiger internal cache uses either 1 GB or half of the installed physical RAM, whichever is larger). For systems with more than 10 GB of RAM, the new default setting is greater than the 3.0 setting.

---

to limit the wiredTriggered Cache Add following line to .config file :

wiredTigerCacheSizeGB = 1

Comment: Here's the docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/#storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB — in Mongo 3.2,  seems the config value name is: `storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB`, but `--wiredTigerCacheSizeGB` is a _command line_ param?

Answer (score 1):

We were experiencing a similar issue on a live/production server which was a member of a replica set, so restarting the process was not an option. Eventho it is not a good idea to flush RES memory (Residence memory), in our use case we had to do it, via following command:

```
yes | tr \\n x | head -c $((1024*1024*1000)) | grep n
```

It create a process that will take over the RAM for 1GB, forcing mongodb to release memory for this process. This was for a system with 2GB of ram. If for example your system is using 20GB of RAM, you might need to run this for 10GB or 15GB:

```
yes | tr \\n x | head -c $((1024*1024*15000)) | grep n
```

Comment: TIL a new Linux command yes

Answer (score 0):

What was my issue:

Because the application deployed on machine from very long time and no historical data was removed which caused increase in size of database used with application. Mongodb occupies almost more than double the size of available data in RAM which was not leaving any free memory to run application.

Memory status before data deleted:

[root@ip-172-31-1-173 logs]# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15630       11462         146         732        4021        3207
Swap:             0           0           0

Memory status after data deleted:

[root@ip-172-31-1-173 mongo]# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15630        5849        5234         788        4545        8763
Swap:             0           0           0

With WiredTiger, MongoDB utilizes both the WiredTiger internal cache and the filesystem cache.

Changed in version 3.2: Starting in MongoDB 3.2, the WiredTiger internal cache, by default, will use the larger of either:

```
60% of RAM minus 1 GB, or
1 GB.
```

For systems with up to 10 GB of RAM, the new default setting is less than or equal to the 3.0 default setting (For MongoDB 3.0, the WiredTiger internal cache uses either 1 GB or half of the installed physical RAM, whichever is larger).

For systems with more than 10 GB of RAM, the new default setting is greater than the 3.0 setting.

Via the filesystem cache, MongoDB automatically uses all free memory that is not used by the WiredTiger cache or by other processes. Data in the filesystem cache is compressed.

You also need to repair database when you cleanup your historical data to maintain size of used cache.