# How to free disk storage of deleted collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

MongoDB does provide a [compact command](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/compact+Command) to free deleted space on a single collection, but my collection are actually deleted and no longer exists.

Then how can I free the deleted space? `repairDatabase()` is not a good idea since the whole database is really really large, larger than `5TBs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am afraid that there is no other options except repairDatabase() will help you here since the entire collection is deleted.

you can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555938/auto-compact-the-deleted-space-in-mongodb) for more info