# Is it possible to reduce the MongoDB memory usage?

Tags: mongodb

I am undergoing testing with 64-bit MongoDB. If I configure large size backups then the MongoDB memory utilization seems to be high.

Is there any possibility to reduce the memory utilization by MongoDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Is it ideal that MongoDB is using 150 MB memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918443/is-it-ideal-that-mongodb-is-using-150-mb-memory/4918676#4918676)

Answer (score 2):

Update /etc/security/limits.conf

Add a line as below:

@mongodb        -    rss              33554432

and then save the file.

It will take effects right away.

In this example, we assign 32GB memory usage for mongodb group users

Comment: I think your method is probably deprecated, because `man limits.conf` indicates:   `rss  maximum resident set size (KB) (Ignored in Linux 2.4.30 and higher)`

Answer (score 1):

For Windows it seems possible to control the amount of memory MongoDB uses, see this tutorial at Captain Codeman:

[Limit MongoDB memory use on Windows without Virtualization](http://www.captaincodeman.com/2011/02/27/limit-mongodb-memory-use-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean memory usage or disk space? If you are really talking about memory, then Mongo stores its data in memory-mapped files, giving the illusion of massive memory usage.

You will find more information here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Checking+Server+Memory+Usage

Comment: I meant for memory usage.K thanks for your kind attention on my question and replied to it..