# 1 million documents in MongoDB 1.4 GB of memory

Tags: mongodb, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to reduce the MongoDB memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018200/is-it-possible-to-reduce-the-mongodb-memory-usage)

My DB .bson size - 1.53 Gb (~1 million documents); 
My memory - 1.4 Gb

```
mongorestore --db database --collection doc /doc.bson
```

It was added to the database and 225,358 documents began errors: file / var/lib/mongodb/database.3 open / create failed in createPrivateMap (look in log for more information) code: 13636 3ms

Would it be possible somehow to boot the database size with so much memory? Can somehow insert piece by piece (.bson)?

Comment: @fvu I have a problem when importing the database, and not in use. How do I insert my base completely?

Comment: (1) 1.5 GB of RAM is very low for a system running MongoDB.  (2) There isn't enough information here to diagnose the problem.  Can you post the log file containing the error messages that 'mongorestore' is referring to.

Comment: 'mongorestore' will insert your data one document at a time.  It is not a "batch-style" insertion.

Comment: I watched the resources and when memory was 100 KB mongo started writing error.

Comment: What OS and OS version are you using?  What tool did you use to monitor memory?

Comment: You're probably running out of disk space.  What error is reported in the log file?