# Automating Resetting MongoDb Service

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, ram

In light of Mongo's caching memory issue (I just had it max out after a week at 2 gigs and stop responding to requests), I've been manually restarting the Mongod.exe service to release all unused memory (see [how to release the caching which is used by Mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468873/how-to-release-the-caching-which-is-used-by-mongodb/4482465#4482465)).  Anybody have any ideas about how to automate this restarting process?  Can you kill the database itself, not just the connection to the database, with the Mongo C# driver?  Maybe have it do so when it reaches a certain % of RAM usage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To shutdown: MongoServer.Shutdown()
To restart: System.Diagnostics.Process to open mongod.exe

[Mongodb server Start after MongoServer.Shutdown()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904185/mongodb-server-start-after-mongoserver-shutdown/7904385#7904385)

Answer (score -1):

Well, as a poors mans solution a scheduled job on the server could restart the service every say 24h