# Mongodb server Start after MongoServer.Shutdown()

Tags: c#, mongodb

What is the opposite function to MongoServer.Shutdown()?  Unlike Disconnect, Shutdown actually shuts down the server.  I want to programmatically boot up the server after I shut it down.  MongoServer.Create() seems to only create an instance of a connection to the server.  It doesn't actually boot up the server if it's been shut down.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shutdown command connects to the server and tells it to shutdown.  If there is no running server, you can't connect to it to tell it to start!

To start the server from your C# program, you could just start the mongod process, by using the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class for example.

Answer (score 0):

On a windows machine and mysql installed as a service, you could try to start the server.