# memory-safe mongodb tasks

Tags: mongodb, memory, crash

MongoDB is running out of memory on a 96GB root server when adding a single index on a timestamp field for a 50GB collection.

Does MongoDB have any option to run a query or task in "safe-mode", e.g. without cutting the memory too much? It seems to be very touchy and can be crashed, e.g. by running some find queries with $lte/$gt on a non-indexed timestamp field.

Comment: yes, 2.6.32-5-amd64, debian.

Comment: is this ok or "incompatible" with mongo? dmesg | grep -i numa
[    0.000000] NUMA: Allocated memnodemap from 40000 - 58840
[    0.000000] NUMA: Using 20 for the hash shift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i can't control it, but shouldn't there a mongodb config setting for "safety" which makes sure to release RAM once it's breaking the limit? maybe even before it is blocking other processes or stoped by oom killer?

MongoDB does not use its own memory management. Instead it uses the OS' LRU. The OS is paging documents so heavily because it has used the amount of memory allocated to `mongod`, aka your working set is bigger than the amount of RAM you have spare for MongoDB as such MongoDB is swapping page faults for most of it not all of your data ( a good reference for paging: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging ).

I would strongly not recommend restricting MongoDB in this case since it will run even worse however, especially on Linux, you can actually use `ulimit` on the `mongo` user you are using to run `mongod`: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/ulimit/

> Does MongoDB have any option to run a query or task in "safe-mode", e.g. without cutting the memory too much?

Not really.

> It seems to be very touchy and can be crashed, e.g. by running some find queries with $lte/$gt on a non-indexed timestamp field.

Naturally this shouldn't cause an OOM exception for MongoDB, it could indicate a memory leak somewhere: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/ulimit/

> If you limit the resident memory size on a system running MongoDB you risk allowing the operating system to terminate the mongod process under normal situations. Do not set this value. If the operating system (i.e. Linux) kills your mongod, with the OOM killer, check the output of serverStatus and ensure MongoDB is not leaking memory.

Comment: i can't believe my RAM is to less. the only collection i use is 50GB, total RAM is a bit less than 96GB. it has only 1 single index on a hash field. of course, it's worth to try a index on the timestamp to get in "ordered". but this shouldn't be the reason for being unstable currently and regularly killed by oom killer when some .find queries are done. apart from .find there are around 20 inserts per second. in my opinion that's not a lot, especially when there is hardly any index.

Comment: @ledy Not it isn't there might be another problem here, I think you might be getting a memory leak, I added an edit about it

Comment: ulimit should be fine: ulimit -a   http://nopaste.info/340ff18546.html    and serverStatus has no warning: mem {
   "bits": NumberInt(64),
   "resident": NumberInt(35877),
   "virtual": NumberInt(393373),
   "supported": true,
   "mapped": NumberInt(196545),
   "mappedWithJournal": NumberInt(393090) 
}

Comment: @ledy Yea, it might seem that physically containing MongoDB might work here, it might be interesting to get to the bottom of this though, it could be bug a somewhere that is making MongoDB just puke all up over the place

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to be very touchy and can be crashed e.g. by running some find queries with $lte/$gt on a non-indexed timestamp field.

It's the OOM killer that's killing it because your mongod instance is swapping a lot pages into RAM. You probably have a lot processes contending for RAM. You can instruct Linux to not kill the mongod daemon as follows :

```
sudo echo -17 > /proc/<process if of mongod>/oom_adj
```

You can't control how much memory mongodb uses, unfortunately. I suggest looking at the [background indexing docs on mongodb](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#index-creation-background). And some more useful links  :

1. [See the related thread on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468873/how-to-release-the-caching-which-is-used-by-mongodb/4482465#4482465)
2. [How do i limit the cache size?](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#how-do-i-configure-the-cache-size)

Comment: i can't control it, but shouldn't there a mongodb config setting for "safety" which makes sure to release RAM once it's breaking the limit? maybe even before it is blocking other processes or stoped by oom killer?

Comment: There isn't one, mongodb relies on the OS's Virtual Memory Manager to swap data files. I've updated answer with the relevant links.