# mongod memory leak inserting documents via C++ drivers

Tags: c++, mongodb, memory, memory-leaks

I am looping over a series of CSV files row by row. For each row I create a BSONObjBuilder object and then add builder.obj() to a std::vector ... every 10k rows I insert the vector to the database and then clear the vector

```
mdb.insert(collection, myvector);
myvector.clear()
```

There are millions of rows in each CSV files. I have noticed that the mongod process is taking up more and more RAM.... until eventually the memory usage is at 100%

```
PID   USER     PR  NT VIRT   RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM
4450 mongod    15   0 73.2g  34g  33g S 45.7 97.0   3848:30 mongod
```

What is going on here? It seems to me like there is a memory leak? There is definitely no memory leak in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `clear`, it clears the elements, but might not reduce the capacity.

This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111078/reduce-the-capacity-of-an-stl-vector)

Either Old skool;

```
std::vector<T>(v).swap(v);
```

Note that C++11 has `shrink_to_fit` which might help, but may do nothing.

Comment: I just ran my code again, this time I insert builder.obj() on every row so I don't use a vector, and I am getting the same memory leak. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: No sorry - just the clear on a vector was a warning to me. How many bytes are your files? How much RAM is mongodb using?

Comment: It seems that my issue was not a memory leak, this post seems to address the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468873/how-to-release-the-caching-which-is-used-by-mongodb/4482465#4482465