# mongod clean memory used in ram

Tags: mongodb, ram, bigdata

I have a huge amount of data in my mongodb. It's filled with tweets (50 GB) and my Ram is 8 GB. When querying it retrieves all tweets and mongodb starts filling the ram, when it reaches 8 GB it starts moving files to disk. This is the part where it gets really slowwwww. So i changed the query from skipping and starting using indexes. Now  i have indexes and i query only 8GB to my program, save the id of the last tweet used in a file and the program stops. Then restart the program and it goes get the id of the tweet from the file. But mogod server still is ocupping the ram with the first 8GB, that no longer will be used, because i have a index to the last. How can i clean the memory of the mongo db server without restarting it?

(running in a win)

Comment: Although it is a bit late (4 years after you asked): I figured that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861184/is-there-any-option-to-limit-mongodb-memory-usage and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861184/is-there-any-option-to-limit-mongodb-memory-usageactually contains helpful information on limiting MongoDB memory usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit confused by your logic here.

> So i changed the query from skipping and starting using indexes. Now i have indexes and i query only 8GB to my program, save the id of the last tweet used in a file and the program stops.

Using ranged queries will not help the amount of data you have to page in (in fact it might worsen it because of the index), it merely makes the query faster server side by using an index for huge skips (like 42K+ row skip). If you are dong the same as that `skip()` but in index then (without a covered index) then you are still paging in exactly the same.

It is slow due to memory mapping and your working set. You have more data than RAM and not only that but you are using more of that data than you have RAM as such you are page faulting probably all the time.

Restarting the program will not solve this, nor will clearing its data OS side (with restart or specific command) because of your queries. You probably need to either:

- Think about your queries so that your working set is more in line to your memory
- Or shard your data across many servers so that you don't have to build up your primary server
- Or get a bigger primary server (moar RAM!!!!!)

#### Edit

The LRU of your OS should be swapping out old data already since MongoDB is using its fully allocated lot, which means that if that 8GB isn't swapped it is because your working set is taking that full 8GB (most likely with some swap on the end).

Comment: when i restart mongo db the RAM goes from 8GB to 0.5 GB, and the first page is not loaded when i want the second (this was appending when using skip). My question is, can i free this memory without restarting mongo db server?

Comment: @user1132271 There might be: http://www.gtricks.com/uncategorized/speed-up-windows-clear-ram-without-restarting/#/vanilla/discussion/embed/?vanilla_discussion_id=0 but as I said I would recommend instead fixing the problem

Comment: Why an object that is loaded one time stays in the memory ram used by the mongo server for so long? I close de connection from the client and the server still has that record loaded. There is no way of that record be release?

Comment: @user1132271 Here is a good explanation in the wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging#Overview about the second paragraph down which states when Windows LRU will take out your old data.