# Node.js, Redis, and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis

## Intoduction

My current project has a mix of common RESTful API concepts and modern realtime websocket/long poling. I'm using mongoDB to store persistant data such as users, products, and aggregated social content. The social content is basically links to tumblr posts, twitter tweets, and facebook posts which are compiled into what I call a "shout".

### Implementation

What I'm trying to accomplish is rating "shouts" based on how many likes or follows the post has out of the combined total from all social medias used. I want the data to change on the frontend as the backend updates. The back-end calls all the social medias based on checking an expiration date on the data. The server will check for new data on event that a request was made for the data. A request is made for the data every time a client connects, or everytime someone posts a new shout through my app. If there is not activity in a given duration of time, the shout is archived and updated every so often with scheduled jobs. I use socket.io to send realtime updates.

### What I'm Using Redis For

The reason I need Redis is to message all my servers when one of them starts requesting data from the social media sources so I don't run into the issue where all of my servers are essentially doing the same thing when the task only needs to be done once. I also need to message my other services once a change is made. For these implementations I'm currently using Redis pub/sub. Since I'm currently using Redis, I also store session tokens in redis, and use it as a cache.

### What I'm Using Mongo For

I use MongoDB to persist data, and I've setup indexing to tune performance specifically for my application.

### The Problem

My problem is I feel like my stack is too big. I feel like using redis and mongo can be over kill. Should I cut out redis and use an MQ system, and store my sessions and cache in mongo and just index them for fast lookups? If so what MQ system would be suitable for my application?

Should I cut out mongodb and use all redis? Would this be cost effective for relatively large sums of data? As I would be storing hundreds of thousands(maybe more) shouts(essentially just URIs), thousands of users, and hundreds of thousands of products.

Comment: My quick reaction to this is that this doesn't seem unreasonably complex, and it's not like switching from Redis to MQ would reduce your stack (although it might possibly take care of things that you would otherwise need to code yourself). I think a lot of people use Redis as a sort of 'shared memory' across servers. I would also say it seems generally sound to separate out your real persistent store (current mongo contents) from your working store (cache, sessions).

Comment: I guess I'm looking for something that might be lighter than redis, though redis is pretty light. The reason I use redis is as basically an MQ. I just decided to use it for caching because it's already there.

Comment: I guess I'm looking at whether or not moving my MQ system to the same server as mongo to save money on hosting is a good idea. However, redis and mongo don't play well on the same system cause they both want so much dedicated memory. Problem is, is that I'm concerned about performance costs of running an MQ service and Mongo on the same machine.

Comment: Yes - both can be quite memory hungry but you're right that redis is 'light' in most other respects. I believe you can configure both to be less greedy about their memory allocations. Although the impact on performance would be an open question with respect to how well your dataset would fit (each portion of) memory. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861184/is-there-any-option-to-limit-mongodb-memory-usage) for some discussion around it.

Comment: Overall, if I were you I would opt for the economy and at least give running both on one machine a try - the nice thing about the combination is you have a trivial way to split up load very, very easily if or when a single machine is no longer practical.

Comment: @barry-johnson I suppose I could try it and if performance is slow I can just put Redis on another server and consider my solutions from their.