# MongoDB - lot of inserts, RAM issue

Tags: vb.net, mongodb, ram

i'm using mongoDB with c# driver. I need to insert 1000 records every 300ms with a timer function. What i'm seeing, is that the memory used by the OS slowly increases until the system stucks. 
I don't understand if mongoDB is able to do this.
By looking at db_stats, i can see that page faults increases during the execution of my application.

Here is the code:

```
//Timer elapsed function (called every 300ms)
Private Function NewDataReceived(ByVal arBytes As Byte())
    dtTimestamp = Now

        Task.Run(Sub()

                     If arBytes.Length >= 60775 Then
                         oDocument = New PLCDocument
                         oDocument.srTimestamp = dtTimestamp.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_fff")
                         oDocument.value = Compress(arBytes)

                         oMongoCollectionPLC.InsertOneAsync(oDocument)


                         lstEventRecords = New List(Of EventDocument)
                         For i As Integer = 0 To lstTags.Count - 1
                             oMyTag = lstTags(i)

                             Select Case oMyTag.iDataType

                                 Case TagDataTypeEnumerator.eTypeOfDataBOOL
                                     arTempArray = New Byte(0) {}
                                     Array.Copy(arBytes, oMyTag.iTagOffset, arTempArray, 0, 1)

                                 Case TagDataTypeEnumerator.eTypeOfDataINT
                                     arTempArray = New Byte(1) {}
                                     Array.Copy(arBytes, oMyTag.iTagOffset, arTempArray, 0, 2)

                                 Case TagDataTypeEnumerator.eTypeOfDataREAL
                                     arTempArray = New Byte(3) {}
                                     Array.Copy(arBytes, oMyTag.iTagOffset, arTempArray, 0, 4)

                                 Case TagDataTypeEnumerator.eTypeOfDataSTRING
                                     arTempArray = New Byte(49) {}
                                     Array.Copy(arBytes, oMyTag.iTagOffset, arTempArray, 0, 50)

                                 Case TagDataTypeEnumerator.eTypeOfDataBIGINT
                                     arTempArray = New Byte(7) {}
                                     Array.Copy(arBytes, oMyTag.iTagOffset, arTempArray, 0, 8)

                             End Select

                             If oMyTag.dtLastTrendInserted.Ticks = 0 Then
                                 'First insert
                                 oMyTag.dtLastTrendInserted = dtTimestamp
                                 oEventRecord = New EventDocument
                                 oEventRecord.iTagID = i
                                 oEventRecord.srTimestamp = dtTimestamp.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_fff")
                                 oEventRecord.value = arTempArray
                                 lstEventRecords.Add(oEventRecord)
                                 lstLastValuesInserted.Add(oEventRecord)
                             Else
                                 bWriteValueToDB = False
                                 Try
                                     Select Case oMyTag.iDataType
                                         'Real -> always write
                                         Case TagDataTypeEnumerator.eTypeOfDataREAL
                                             oEventRecord = New EventDocument
                                             oEventRecord.iTagID = i
                                             oEventRecord.srTimestamp = dtTimestamp.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_fff")
                                             oEventRecord.value = arTempArray
                                             lstEventRecords.Add(oEventRecord)
                                             lstLastValuesInserted(i) = oEventRecord

                                         Case TagDataTypeEnumerator.eTypeOfDataBOOL
                                             If BitConverter.ToBoolean(lstLastValuesInserted(i).value, 0) <> BitConverter.ToBoolean(arTempArray, 0) Then
                                                 bWriteValueToDB = True
                                             End If
                                         Case TagDataTypeEnumerator.eTypeOfDataINT
                                             If BitConverter.ToInt16(lstLastValuesInserted(i).value, 0) <> BitConverter.ToInt16(arTempArray, 0) Then
                                                 bWriteValueToDB = True
                                             End If
                                         Case TagDataTypeEnumerator.eTypeOfDataSTRING
                                             If BitConverter.ToString(lstLastValuesInserted(i).value, 0) <> BitConverter.ToString(arTempArray, 0) Then
                                                 bWriteValueToDB = True
                                             End If
                                         Case TagDataTypeEnumerator.eTypeOfDataBIGINT
                                             If BitConverter.ToInt64(lstLastValuesInserted(i).value, 0) <> BitConverter.ToInt64(arTempArray, 0) Then
                                                 bWriteValueToDB = True
                                             End If

                                     End Select
                                 Catch ex As Exception
                                     LogErrorManagement.writeLogToFile(String.Format("ERROR! i:{0} lstLastValuesInserted(i).value:{1}", i, lstLastValuesInserted(i).value), ex)
                                 End Try

                                 If bWriteValueToDB Then
                                     oMyTag.dtLastTrendInserted = dtTimestamp
                                     oEventRecord = New EventDocument
                                     oEventRecord.iTagID = i
                                     oEventRecord.srTimestamp = dtTimestamp.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_fff")
                                     oEventRecord.value = arTempArray
                                     lstEventRecords.Add(oEventRecord)
                                     lstLastValuesInserted(i) = oEventRecord
                                 End If

                             End If

                         Next

                         oMongoCollectionEvents.InsertManyAsync(lstEventRecords)

                         'End If

                     End If

                 End Sub)

End Function
```

mongod.exe server is running on the same pc as mongoclient used in the application.
RAM installed in my pc: 8gb.

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: RAM issue where? On the machine running the application or on the server?

Comment: both server and client are running on the same machine. so the machine is just one

Comment: Well I see async calls here and no wating for them to resolve, so that's going to start eating RAM quite quickly. You should remember that a database is most happy when it has "free reign" over the available resources, and starts to throw it's own "fits" when something else is competing from those resources. I would suggest whatever gains are be coming from no network latency or overhead are being lost in the application design. Don't load big lists to memory and consider separating database and application to separate resources.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any option to limit mongodb memory usage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861184/is-there-any-option-to-limit-mongodb-memory-usage)