# MongoDB is not releasing memory

Tags: mongodb, memory

I am having a MongoDB Server with 16GB of RAM , I see there are no running processes onto it and still it doesn't release the Memory , it shows 10GB of memory occupied by Monngo.

What could be the possible reasons ?

Comment: It seems like a basic functionality of mongodb. Visit the following url to get more knowledge about mongodb's memory management. There are some other external links too. Hope you will find a way to resolve the issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861184/is-there-any-option-to-limit-mongodb-memory-usage

Comment: Do you have collections that have indices? Those indices are loaded into the RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch file containing the mongodb service restart command and schedule it on the Task scheduler as per your requirement.

MongoDB service restart command:

powershell -command "Restart-Service MONGODB -Force"

MongoDB does not have any setting to release memory back to the operating system.

I have the solution for this and I already had implemented this and working fine.