# MongoDB memory consumption - it keeps rising

Tags: mongodb, performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I run a mongodb server in a EC2 instance on AWS. For a while it ran flawlessly, nevery spiking above 50% of memory usage.

Suddenly, the behaviour changed to an ever increasing curve, it never goes significantly down, it keeps growing througout the day, until it reaches a peak (sometimes it is 100%, sometimes 90 or 80) and suddenly drops to 50% (perhaps some Hypervisor activity here?).

This behavior is NOT, in any way, compatible with the usage behavior of the application server this database is serving. Below is a graph comparing incoming requests x db memory usage.

[image]

What are the things I should be looking into to diagnose this memory issue? I already looked at the amount of open connections at any given time, and it is very low (<20), so I don't think it could be that. Any other ideas?

This issue doesn't seem to impact database performance, but I can't run any maintenance jobs (like archiving and backup) with memory that high - I had cases in which the database crashed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861184/is-there-any-option-to-limit-mongodb-memory-usage

Comment: What are your specific versions of MongoDB server and O/S? Have you changed any MongoDB configuration settings from the default?

Comment: Mongo 3.2.17, Amazon Linux. The settings are very basic and I haven't changed it.