# How to limit amount of server memory a mongodb query uses?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongodb. I have around 700,000 documents in a collection in my db. When I try to make a find call, mongodb crashes. I've found out from looking at `dmesg` that OOM killer is killing mongod after it consumes a lot of RAM.

We just have 1GiB of RAM. I'd like to know how I can make mongo db take less RAM than it takes right now for making a find query. Is there a way I can configure mongodb in such a way.

I've looked at another SO answer and tried uncommenting wired tiger and setting to

```
  wiredTiger:
    engineConfig:
      cacheSizeGB: 0.1
```

and did a `systemctl restart mongod`, and it still crashes for find with a query.

I've also found many questions and blogposts describing this problem, but none say there exists a solution.  Can anything be done with configs that will prevent mongodb crashing / taking up less memory for all mongod operations?

Answer (score 0):

It may help you.

```
storage:
 wiredTiger:
  engineConfig:
    configString : cache_size=345M
```

From Here:
[Is there any option to limit mongodb memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861184/is-there-any-option-to-limit-mongodb-memory-usage)